# list of method references which are causing DexIndexOverflowException

Tags: android, android-studio, android-multidex

I am facing a problem which is causing `com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536`.

I know the use of `multiDexEnabled` but i don't want to implement or use it as it has some Limitations.

One of it is :

> Applications that use multidex may not start on devices that run
>   versions of the platform earlier than Android 4.0 (API level 14) due
>   to a Dalvik linearAlloc bug (Issue 22586). If you are targeting API
>   levels earlier than 14, make sure to perform testing with these
>   versions of the platform as your application can have issues at
>   startup or when particular groups of classes are loaded. Code
>   shrinking can reduce or possibly eliminate these potential issues.

referenced by Google [link](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#limitations)

**I want to know a way that can show me the list of method references which are causing this issue.** so that i can remove such modules while importing the library which i have already in my project.

Example :

```
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
```

Comment: https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using multi-dex temporarily, and then use baksmali to do an annotated hex dump of the resulting dex files. The annotated hex dump will include the method reference list.

```
baksmali -N -D out.dump -e classes.dex myapp.apk
baksmali -N -D out2.dump -e classes2.dex myapp.apk
```

You'll want to look for "method_id_item section" in the 2 dump files. This section has the full list of method references used in the dex file. It will look something like

```
                           |-----------------------------
                           |method_id_item section
                           |-----------------------------
                           |
                           |[0] method_id_item
003c38: 0500               |  class_idx = type_id_item[5]: Lafzkl/development/mColorPicker/drawables/AlphaPatternDrawable;
003c3a: b000               |  proto_idx = proto_id_item[176]: (I)V
003c3c: 1900 0000          |  name_idx = string_id_item[25]: <init>
                           |[1] method_id_item
003c40: 0500               |  class_idx = type_id_item[5]: Lafzkl/development/mColorPicker/drawables/AlphaPatternDrawable;
003c42: d500               |  proto_idx = proto_id_item[213]: (Landroid/graphics/Canvas;)V
003c44: df02 0000          |  name_idx = string_id_item[735]: draw
                           |[2] method_id_item
003c48: 0500               |  class_idx = type_id_item[5]: Lafzkl/development/mColorPicker/drawables/AlphaPatternDrawable;
003c4a: a400               |  proto_idx = proto_id_item[164]: ()V
003c4c: 4103 0000          |  name_idx = string_id_item[833]: generatePatternBitmap
                           |[3] method_id_item
003c50: 0500               |  class_idx = type_id_item[5]: Lafzkl/development/mColorPicker/drawables/AlphaPatternDrawable;
003c52: 4500               |  proto_idx = proto_id_item[69]: ()Landroid/graphics/Rect;
003c54: 4e03 0000          |  name_idx = string_id_item[846]: getBounds
                           |[4] method_id_item
003c58: 0500               |  class_idx = type_id_item[5]: Lafzkl/development/mColorPicker/drawables/AlphaPatternDrawable;
003c5a: 0c00               |  proto_idx = proto_id_item[12]: ()I
003c5c: 8403 0000          |  name_idx = string_id_item[900]: getOpacity
...
```

An alternate approach would be to write a little tool using [dexlib2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.smali/dexlib2) to read the dex file and print out the method refereneces.

```
public class DumpMethods {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DexBackedDexFile dexFile = DexFileFactory.loadDexFile(args[0], 15);

        for (int i=0; i<dexFile.getMethodCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(ReferenceUtil.getMethodDescriptor(new DexBackedMethodReference(dexFile, i)));
        }
    }
}
```

This will print out the method references in a simple list:

```
Lafzkl/development/mColorPicker/drawables/AlphaPatternDrawable;-><init>(I)V
Lafzkl/development/mColorPicker/drawables/AlphaPatternDrawable;->draw(Landroid/graphics/Canvas;)V
Lafzkl/development/mColorPicker/drawables/AlphaPatternDrawable;->generatePatternBitmap()V
Lafzkl/development/mColorPicker/drawables/AlphaPatternDrawable;->getBounds()Landroid/graphics/Rect;
Lafzkl/development/mColorPicker/drawables/AlphaPatternDrawable;->getOpacity()I
...
```